# Detecting Win API mouse_event Call

Tags: visual-c++, dll-injection

I would like to write a program that will determine whether the mouse is being moved by a human or by a different process calling the User32 SendInput function. I thought that perhaps it would be possible to use dll injection to detect when SendInput is called, but I don't have any experience with this - is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [low level mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the `LLMHF_INJECTED` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft [**Detours**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) library allows you to get notification for function calls.

> Detours is a library for instrumenting arbitrary Win32 functions Windows-compatible processors. Detours ***intercepts Win32 functions*** by re-writing the in-memory code for target functions. The Detours package also contains utilities to attach arbitrary DLLs and data segments (called payloads) to any Win32 binary.